# How to fix runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type' (stl_vector.h) in LeetCode?

Tags: c++11, dynamic-programming

This is the code and I can't understand where is it going out of bound for this error.

```
class Solution {
public:
int maxProfit(vector<int>& prices) {
    int min=prices[0],profit=0,best_profit=0;
    int n=prices.size();
    if (n<2) return 0;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        profit=prices[i]-min;
        best_profit = (profit > best_profit) ? profit : best_profit;

       if(min>prices[i])
            min=prices[i];
    }
    return best_profit;

}
};
```

Comment: What happens in `prices[0]` when `prices` is empty?

Answer (score 0):

The only possible reason is `price[0]` on the 4th line. It's behavior is undefined if the `vector` is empty.

By the way, if you won't change the `vector` in the function, declare it as const reference.